# How can I integrate Sencha Touch 2 into Cordova (Phonegap) project

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to integrate a ST2 app into PhoneGap; but I'm having problems.

I've added cordova.js into app.json:

```
{   
    "path": "resources/js/cordova-1.6.1.js",
    "update": "delta"
},
{   
    "path": "resources/js/test.js",
    "update": "delta"
}
```

Test.js :

```
function alertDismissed() {}

function showAlert() {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        'You are the winner!',  // message
        alertDismissed,         // callback
        'Game Over',            // title
        'Done'                  // buttonName
    );
}
```

Inside a view, i've created a dummy button:

```
items: [{
    text: 'test',
    action: showAlert(),
}],
```

When i tap the button; the function 'showAlert()' is fired up correctly; but not being executed correctly i have an error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'alert' of undefined
```

Obviously because the object 'navigator' is not being instenciated.

Question: is it possible to have both cordova/senchatouch2 run ? 
If so, what is the proper way to do it ?

SOLVED:

Add cordova.js prior to app.js

```
    {   
        "path": "resources/js/cordova-1.6.1.js",
        "update": "delta"
    },
    {
        "path": "sdk/sencha-touch.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "update": "delta"
    },
```

Comment: Could you kindly, share the project structure/folder with me. I am also having the same issue for more than a week. I am still stuck :( . Please share me the project folder so i could use it to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the cordova.js file from the index.html file.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using iOS or Android SDK for your app. I have 3 published apps using phonegap and ST. And all I do is to include the cordova in the html file. Can you provide more information about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes iOS. Well just a simple bare app to test the integration. Have you been using Sencha Touch 2 ?

Comment: Yes ST2. So step by step, you created the app in xCode based on phonegap and tested it. After this you integrated the ST code using the following line: <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>?

Comment: No, i've created the whole app structure using sencha's command line ' sencha generate app' but it's the same result; i still have index.html etc.

Comment: Good, after creating the ST app, copy all files (except index.html) to the www folder inside your xcode app. Then add that line <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script> to the index.html of the phonegap app. Don't forget to remove the content inside <body></body> of your phonegap index.html.

Comment: Solved; see my edit. Modifying index.html is not a good idea as it may break the commandline tool.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article about "**A Sencha Touch MVC application with PhoneGap**" http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/

Comment: I followed this post and only got a blank screen. This post seems really out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer following blog to integrate senchatouch and phonegap with custom plugin:

http://hynridmobileapps.blogspot.in/