# How to integrate Sencha Touch app into Cordova XCode project?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I'm wondering how I can integrate Sencha Touch projects into a Cordova project.

I know that with current Sencha Cmd we can generate a Cordova project from the Sencha code, but the code is compressed and not flexible for changes. (For example, the official Facebook sdk does not work any more after this build, I will have to work with the Cordova-facebook-plugin).

So I created a new Cordova project, and as a beginning, I created a new helloWorld sencha touch app. I removed the original stuff in the `www/` folder of the Cordova project and put everything of this Sencha Touch project under it, but the loading was not successful.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384596/how-can-i-integrate-sencha-touch-2-into-cordova-phonegap-project) and realized some extra configurations are needed, but this post seems out-of-date for me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create a sencha touch project and cordova project seperately.

Add the required platform inside your cordova project.This will give you the required platform specific cordova.js file.

Now take the cordova.js file and paste it under the app folder of your sencha project.

Open the app.json file and add mapping to the file like this

```
'Js' : [

{

    'Path' : 'touch / sencha-touch.js' ,

    'X-bootstrap' : true

}

{

   'Path' : 'cordova.js' ,

    'X-bootstrap' : true

}

{

    'Path' : 'app.js' ,

    'Bundle' : true ,

    'Update' : 'delta'

}

]
```

Now you can check in Chrome Developer Tools that cordova.js is included in the project.

Now load your app only after cordova is loaded by including the following function in your app.js file

```
launch: function () {

/ / Destroy the # appLoadingIndicator element

Ext.fly ( 'appLoadingIndicator' ). destroy ();


/ / Wait for cord to be ready

document.addEventListener ( 'deviceready' , function () {


     Ext.Viewport.add (Ext.create ( 'MyApp.view.Main' ));


}, false );

}
```

You can no longer run the project in browser beacuse cordova is include.Use a phone to see your project as an app

Here is the link to detailed tutorial that helped me with my project

http://senchadevelopers.blogspot.in/2013/09/integrating-phonegap-with-sencha-touch.html

Comment: Her code ends up getting compressed code as we can see in the code she gave https://github.com/loiane/phonegap-projects/blob/master/SenchaTouchPhoneGap/native/iOS/www/index.html. How can I get uncompressed code? Thanks a lot

Comment: go to .sencha/app folder and override the default properties specified in package.default.properties

Comment: Sencha minifys code by default in production mode.refer topic deploying your aplication in documentation http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/guide/command_app ...for testing do it in testing mode...final build will be in production mode...but try overriding properties..it worked for me..but many reported it didnt

Comment: in  package.default.properties file,set build.compression.yui=0...this is the property that worked for me.i did this by refering this thread http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273381-How-do-I-disable-minify

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

1. integrate with phonegap details [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/cordova)
2. in your build.xml add the following

> ```
> <target name="-before-init">
>  <property name="build.options.production.debug" value="debug:true"/>
> </target>
> ```

then run sencha app build native.   This might get you an uncompressed version in your phonegap folder.